# Disable RAID to JBOD in server IBM x3400 M2

Tags: boot, bios, centos, raid, ibm-server

Hi I just wanna disable the default RAID in my server IBM System X3400 M2 Server(7837-24X),i have 3 disk drives SAS.
I want to make them a JBOD "Just a Bunch Of Disks", because I want to install in the drive 0 CentOS, and the other two make them cache files for a squid server.
I disable the RAID in the BIOS:

```
System Settings/Adapters and UEFI drivers/LSI Logic Fusion MPT SAS Driver
-PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0X0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)
```

LSI Logic MPT Setup Utility

```
RAID Properties/Delete Array
```

Later I boot the CentOS live CD and install the OS in the drive 0, and the others 2 mounted like this:

```
*LVM Volume Groups
vg_proxyserver     139508
lv_root            51200    /    ext4
lv_home        84276    /home    ext4
lv_swap        4032
Hard Drive
sdb(/dev/sdb)
free        140011
sdc(/dev/sdc)
free        140011
sdd(/dev/sdd)
sdd1        500    /boot    ext4
sdd2        139512 vg_proxyserver    physical volume(LVM)
```

But when I restart the server give me the error:

```
Boot failed Hard Disk 0
UEFI PXE PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0X0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(001A64B15130,0X0))
........PXE-E18:Server response timeout.
UEFI PXE PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0X0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(001A64B15132,0X0))
........PXE-E18:Server response timeout.
```

and the OS not start. The IBM force me to do a RAID?,why?

Comment: When exactly is IBM forcing you to do a RAID? These error messages means that it is trying to boot from network using PXE. Try to look at boot order in bios, check boot flag on boot partition, check grub install in mbr and be sure that you have a lvm support in your initram.

Comment: How I do this (be sure that you have a lvm support in your initram)?sorry for the silly question.

Comment: And when I configure the Hard Drive with RAID 0, RAID 1-E, the system boot normal with centOS (my controller of RAID is - Model Hot-swap with PCI-Express ServeRAID-BR10i for RAID-0, -1 and 1-E)